# Having trouble updating database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database called specials with a table called specials, the table has 6 rows, there are 3 records a record with an id of 1,2, and 3. One of the rows is called title. I have data already there but I want to update the data using a form. How ever my mysqli_query is not working.

Here is my code.

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title=san diego WHERE id='1'");
```

Comment: You need quotes around san diego.

Comment: try SET title='san diego' with quotes

Comment: corrected:-  UPDATE specials SET title='san diego' WHERE id='1'

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE from SELECT using SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming title is **varchar** and id is **int**

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title='san diego' WHERE id=1");
```

Answer (score 1):

you are inserting a string in `varchar` field so it should be quoted also try

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title='san diego' WHERE id=1");
```

if datatype is **varchar** string should be quoted like `title='san diego'`

if **int** no need to quote (but you can use with quote) `id = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title='san diego' WHERE id = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title='san diego' WHERE id=1");
```

If your id is type of **Int** and title of **Varchar**